# Strange behaviour with ng-bind angular

Tags: angularjs

So wanted to have a spinning cube with pictures on, because that is what all the cool kids want. Then decided that I wanted to have it all in a database and use the mean stack, so set that up.

Here comes the problem. On the index.html version, the cube sometimes messes up and moves to the screen blocking everything else out. Just open the link below and click the menu a few different menu options a few time and you'll see what I mean. 
http://v-ghost.port0.org:8081/TESTCube/public/index.html

Worked a long while trying to figure out what was wrong, and it turns out that it is related to how I load the menu, I tried to generate it using ng-bind-html.

```
            <figure class="front"><div id="front-page" ng-bind-html="showpane('front')"></div></figure>
            <figure class="back"><div id="front-page" ng-bind-html="showpane('back')"></div></figure>
            <figure class="right"><div id="front-page" ng-bind-html="showpane('right')"></figure>
            <figure class="left"><div id="front-page" ng-bind-html="showpane('left')"></figure>
            <figure class="top"><div id="front-page" ng-bind-html="showpane('top')"></figure>
            <figure class="bottom"><div id="front-page" ng-bind-html="showpane('bottom')"></figure>
```

Strangely, if I change this to just use text (i.e. less fancy way):

```
    <button class="show-front">Front</button><br/>
    <button class="show-back">Back</button><br/>
    <button class="show-right">Right</button><br/>
    <button class="show-left">Left</button><br/>
    <button class="show-top">Top</button><br/>
    <button class="show-bottom">Bottom</button><br/>
```

Try it on
http://v-ghost.port0.org:8081/TESTCube/public/index-nobind.html, unbreakable (famous last words).

What I can't understand is why, why does me calling a function in a button break the cubes path?
Also, is there an easier way to get the value of a string in an array then building a function to get it in a ng-bind?

Tried to make it as easy as possible to test around, should be just to copy the html if you want to give it a try.

Comment: So I am pretty certain that this is somehow connected to asyncronous something or other, but I really can not figure out how. Even if I set the keys to northing, or if I unload the angular script (OK, saying unload makes it sound so cool, I just misspelled the module). So it is something that happens between the ng-bind and java I thing. Is there a better or simpler way to do this, as I just want to set the text on the button to a name stored in an array from the database (each name paired with a url)

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling about I never manage to figure out why ng-bind behaved like this. And without a error message it was pretty hard to identify the problem.

If you have the same problem, one way to get around it is to just change the controller to present the data under an object. So start by defining the controller as app

```
<body ng-app="DBFScube" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
```

Then call a sub function (getmenuname) for each option.

```
   <button class="show-front">{{app.getmenuname('front')}}</button><br/>
    <button class="show-back">{{app.getmenuname('back')}}</button><br/>
    <button class="show-right">{{app.getmenuname('right')}}</button><br/>
    <button class="show-left">{{app.getmenuname('left')}}</button><br/>
    <button class="show-top">{{app.getmenuname('top')}}</button><br/>
    <button class="show-bottom">{{app.getmenuname('bottom')}}</button>
```

The controller looks like this

```
var app = this;
//
//$http.get("http://localhost:3000").success(function(CubeSides){
  //  app.CubeSides = CubeSides;
//})
$http.get("http://localhost:3000").success(function(CubeSides){
    $scope.sides=CubeSides;
    console.log("Loading data");
})
app.getmenuname = function(side) {
    if($scope.sides === undefined) {
        console.log("Not loaded fside " + side );
    } else {
        console.log("Got menu pane " + $scope.sides);
        var fside = $filter('filter')($scope.sides, function (d) {return d.side === side;})[0];
        console.log("Sending: " + fside.menuname);
        return fside.menuname;
    }
}
```

This probably isn't the right way of doing it, but if all you need to do is set the name on some buttons, it does the trick:)